# DAX Between Dates Function

Tags: powerbi, data-science, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I would like to create a measure where I filter data between two dates.
I would like to see how many customers I had in the previous years so I would like to see the sum of the column "names" from my dataset.

My attempt:

```
L2020 = 
COUNT('customers'[name], DATESBETWEEN('customers'[name], DATE(2020,01,01), DATE(2020,12,31)))
```

I am getting an error code that says "Too many arguments were passed to the SUM function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1."

Comment: try ``L2020 = CALCULATE( COUNT('customers'[name]),``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L2020 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'customers'[name] ),
    DATESBETWEEN ( 'customers'[name], DATE ( 2020, 01, 01 ), DATE ( 2020, 12, 31 ) )
)
```